# Render favorite movies without refresh page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, render

When I click on the heart icon to either delete or add movie to favorites I have to press <kbd>f5</kbd> or put `window.location.reload` to see the changes made. How can I solve this?

```
async function show_popup(card) {
  popup_container.classList.add("show-popup");

  const movie_id = card.dataset.id;

  const movie = await get_movie_by_id(movie_id);
  const movie_trailer = await get_movie_trailer(movie_id);
  popup_container.style.background = `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 9)), url(${
    image_path + movie.poster_path
    })`;

  popup_container.innerHTML = `
            <span class="x-icon">&#10006;</span>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="poster-img">
                        <img src="${image_path + movie.poster_path}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-info">
                        <span>Add to favorites:</span>
                        <span class="heart-icon">&#9829;</span>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <h1>${movie.title}</h1>
                    <h3>${movie.tagline}</h3>
                    <div class="single-info-container">
                        <div class="single-info">
                            <span>Language:</span>
                            <span>${movie.spoken_languages[0].name}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-info">
                            <span>Length:</span>
                            <span>${movie.runtime} minutes</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-info">
                            <span>Rate:</span>
                            <span>${movie.vote_average} / 10</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-info">
                            <span>Budget:</span>
                            <span>$ ${movie.budget}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-info">
                            <span>Release Date:</span>
                            <span>${movie.release_date}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="genres">
                        <h2>Genres</h2>
                        <ul>
                            ${movie.genres
                               .map((e) => `<li>${e.name}</li>`)
                              .join("")}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="overview">
                        <h2>Overview</h2>
                        <p>${movie.overview}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="trailer">
                        <h2>Trailer</h2>
                        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${movie_trailer}" title="YouTube   video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    `;

  const x_icon = document.querySelector(".x-icon");
  x_icon.addEventListener("click", () =>
   popup_container.classList.remove("show-popup")
  );

  const heart_icon = popup_container.querySelector(".heart-icon");
  for (let code of movies_LS) {
    if (code === movie_id) {
      heart_icon.classList.add("change-color");
   }
  }

  heart_icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (heart_icon.classList.contains("change-color")) {
      remove_LS(movie_id);
      heart_icon.classList.remove("change-color");
    } else {
      add_to_LS(movie_id);
      heart_icon.classList.add("change-color");
    }
 });
}

const movies_LS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movie-id")) || [];

function add_to_LS(id) {
 movies_LS.push(id);
  localStorage.setItem("movie-id", JSON.stringify(movies_LS));
}

 function remove_LS(index) {
   let findIndex = movies_LS.findIndex((id) => id === index);
   movies_LS.splice(findIndex, 1);
   localStorage.setItem("movie-id", JSON.stringify(movies_LS));
  }

const favMoviesEl = [];
add_favorites_to_dom_from_LS();
async function add_favorites_to_dom_from_LS() {
  //inside this function it is my issue
  for (let code of movies_LS) {
    let movie = await get_movie_by_id(code);
    favMoviesEl.push(movie);
  }
 
  let mainGridTag = favMoviesEl.map((elements) => {
    const { id, poster_path, title, vote_average, release_date } = elements;
    return `
   <div class="card" data-id="${id}">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="${image_path + poster_path}">
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <h2>${title}</h2>
                <div class="single-info">
                    <span>Rate: </span>
                    <span>${vote_average.toFixed(1)} / 10</span>
                </div>
                <div class="single-info">
                    <span>Release Date: </span>
                    <span>${release_date}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
  });

  main_grid_favorites.innerHTML = mainGridTag.join("");

  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".favorites .card");
  add_click_effect_to_card(cards);
}
```

When I type `console.log(elements)` I can only see the movies that were added before, if I click on the heart to remove or add movie, till I reload the page I won't see in console the object with all the info of the removed or added movie. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Take away everything from your post except the absolute minimum to illustrate the problem. I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but React handles this use case absolutely beautifully.

Comment: From how you handle the code, you should use Web Components or a framework like React, Vue, or Lit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help